# How can I pass view as parameter in android?

Tags: java, android

I want to create notification daily in my android app. For the purpose I made a `createNotification` method. Now, I want to call the method at a particular time. My `mainactivity.java` is as follows:

```
package com.example.shiza.dailyquranquote;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;

import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    Date startDate= new Date("03/31/2015 12:00:00");
    Date endDate = new Date();
    TextView textView ;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.verse);
        long startDay = startDate.getTime() / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24;
        long endDay = endDate.getTime() / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24;
        long daysBetween = endDay - startDay;
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("QuranVerse",0);
        String id = ""+ (daysBetween % 365) ;
        String verse = sharedPreferences.getString(id, "");

        if (verse == null)
        {
            verse ="Sufficient is Allah for me; There is no power except Him; And in Him I put my trust.";
        }

        Calendar rightNow = Calendar.getInstance();
        textView.setText(verse + "current hour is" + rightNow.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        if ( rightNow.HOUR_OF_DAY == 11 )
        {
            createNotification();
        }
    }

    public void goToInsertVerse(View v)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,InsertVerse.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    public void goToGetVerse(View v)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,GetVerse.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    public void createNotification(View view) {
        // Prepare intent which is triggered if the
        // notification is selected
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);

        // Build notification
        // Actions are just fake
        Notification noti = new Notification.Builder(this)
                .setContentTitle("New mail from " + "test@gmail.com")
                .setContentText("Subject").setSmallIcon(R.drawable.background)
                .setContentIntent(pIntent)
                .build();
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        // hide the notification after its selected
        noti.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

        notificationManager.notify(0, noti);

    }
}
```

Now I need to pass **view** as a parameter to `createNotification`. I am unable to do it. How I can achieve it?

Comment: why would you want to pass a view?

Comment: What's your difficulty?  You pass it like you would any other parameter.

Comment: Because createNotification require this. Is it not required in my method?

Comment: @GabeSechan getting error createNotification(view) in main activity can't be applied.

Comment: Because you aren't passing it a parameter and it requires one.  Pass in the view you want as a parameter.  If you don't understand that, it seems like your problem is you don't know how to program.

Comment: @GabeSechan Whenever I am trying to pass a parameter, it gives me error. By the way I liked  **it seems like your problem is you don't know how to program** :D

Comment: You define your method as `public void createNotification(View view)` *BUT* you do nothing within that method which actually uses the `view` parameter....so why are you defining it that way? Change the method definition to be `public void createNotification()` and it will fix the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

user [setContent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html#setContent(android.widget.RemoteViews)) method wich takes "[RemoteViews](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RemoteViews.html)" as parameter